# Divergence rate of inverse Laplace transform of a function with polynomial lower bound and exponential upper bound

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, laplace-transform

I encountered the following problem: Let $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to \mathbb{R}_+$ be a continuous increasing function. Suppose there is $r_0>0$ (however large you want it to be) such that

- 1 ) $Cr^{\alpha}\ge f(r) \ge \frac{1}{C}r^\alpha$ for some $C>0$ and $\alpha>0$ for $r \in [0,r_0]$.
- 2 ) There are $\lambda_0,C>0$ such that $C\exp(\lambda_0 r)\ge f(r) \ge \frac{1}{C}r^\alpha$ for $r\ge r_0$ with same $\alpha$ as in (1).

For a fixed $\epsilon$, we define $F(r)$ to be
\begin{align}
F(r) = \int_0^r\exp(\epsilon s)df(s) \int_0^r\exp(-\epsilon s)df(s).
\end{align}
I am interested in the divergence rate of $F(r)$, do we have something like
\begin{align}
\lim_{r \to \infty} r^{-n}F(r) = \infty,\quad \forall n \ge 1.
\end{align}
Where the integration is in Lebesgue-Stieltjes sense since $f$ is of bounded variation on any finite interval.

I first did a naive Cauchy-Schwarz so $\frac{1}{C'} r^\frac{\alpha}{2}\ge F(r) \ge \frac{1}{C'} r^\frac{\alpha}{2}$. Use the integration by parts formula we can get a more workable expression for $F(r)$, namely:
\begin{align}
F(r) = \left(e^{\epsilon r}f(r) - \epsilon\int_0^re^{\epsilon s}f(s)ds\right)\left(e^{-\epsilon r}f(r) + \epsilon\int_0^re^{-\epsilon s}f(s)ds\right).
\end{align}
So now we can only worry about the first term. When $f(r) = a\exp(br)$ then a simple calculation shows $F(r)$ goes to infinity exponentially fast. I am not familiar with Gamma functions, but from Wolfram Alpha, when $f(r) = r^n$ for integer $n$'s, it also diverges exponentially fast.

We can also use L'Hospital's rule, but that would involve the quantity $f'(r)$ when $r \to \infty$, for which I don't seem to have control of.

Any help will be predicated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not need $f'$ to use L'Hospital's rule: $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{r \to  + \infty } \frac{{\int_0^r {{\rm e}^{\varepsilon s} f(s){\rm d}s} }}{{g(r)}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{r \to  + \infty } \frac{{{\rm e}^{\varepsilon r} f(r)}}{{g'(r)}}.
$$ You need a $g$ that tends to infinity and whose derivative mimics the behaviour of ${{\rm e}^{\varepsilon r} f(r)}$.

Comment: @Gary Thanks for the advice. One thing I don't understand is how to apply this. The integral for $F(x)$ is with respect to $f(s)$, that is $\int_0^t e^{\epsilon s}df(s)$ for which if you differentiate, it becomes $e^{\epsilon t}f'(t)$.